# Paperclip saves in console, not in views, no errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model, paperclip

I have the following model:

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base

  # RELATIONSHIPS
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Folder'
  has_many :subfolders, :class_name => 'Folder', :foreign_key => :parent_id
  has_many :photos

  has_attached_file :image,
                    :styles => { :sixth => "145x109#", :eighth => "106x80#", :tenth => "87x65#" },
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    :path => "collections/:id/:style.:extension",
                    :default_url => '/images/no_folder_image_:style.png'

  ...
end
```

When I do this in the console...

```
f = Folder.first
f.image = "foo.jpg"
f.save!
```

... then the image gets saved and works perfectly.

However, when I try to create or update an image using forms, I get no errors, but it doesn't work.

Here's a sample of the log:

```
Started POST "/collections/community-collection/folders/11" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-03-09 10:31:05 -0600
  Processing by Collections::FoldersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RpY1Ov1oMsA7JhvpNZpvuoJfNaRV8BAjiCbHYkUQSus=", "folder"=>{"name"=>"Test With Image", "parent_id"=>"1", "image"=>"Snowy Chicago.jpg", "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Folder", "collection_id"=>"community-collection", "id"=>"11"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT sluggable_id FROM slugs WHERE ((slugs.sluggable_type = 'Collection' AND slugs.name = 'community-collection' AND slugs.sequence = 1))
  Collection Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles".id = "roles_users".role_id WHERE "roles"."name" = 'admin' AND ("roles_users".user_id = 2 ) LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles".id = "roles_users".role_id WHERE "roles"."name" = 'curator' AND ("roles_users".user_id = 2 ) LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles".id = "roles_users".role_id WHERE "roles"."name" = 'member' AND ("roles_users".user_id = 2 ) LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".*, "users"."id" FROM "users" INNER JOIN "assignments" ON "users".id = "assignments".user_id WHERE "users"."id" = 2 AND (("assignments".collection_id = 1)) LIMIT 1
  Folder Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "folders".* FROM "folders" WHERE "folders"."id" = 11 AND ("folders".collection_id = 1) ORDER BY "folders"."display_order" ASC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE "collections"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
  Slug Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "slugs".* FROM "slugs" WHERE ("slugs".sluggable_id = 1 AND "slugs".sluggable_type = 'Collection') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/collections/community-collection/folders
Completed 302 Found in 375ms
```

Note that it says `[paperclip] Saving attachments.`

Here's are the controller actions:

```
# this before_filter loads the collection folders belong to:
def load_collection
  @collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
end

def create
  if @collection.folders.create(params[:folder])
    redirect_to collection_folders_path(@collection)
  else
     render 'new'
  end
end

def update
  @folder = @collection.folders.find(params[:id])
  if @folder.update_attributes(params[:folder])
    redirect_to collection_folders_path(@collection)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Here's the form:

```
= simple_form_for [@collection, @folder], :html => { :class => 'full' } do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.association :parent
  = f.input :image, :hint => 'Choose an image or icon to represent this folder.'
  = f.input :description
  = f.submit
```

This form works as expected, all other attributes are saved, but for some reason paperclip doesn't work. For what it's worth I know that simple_form isn't the reason, I have other virtually identical forms on other models with paperclip attachments that all work perfectly.

What am I missing here???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the multipart attribute to true

```
simple_form_for [@collection, @folder], :html => { :class => 'full', :multipart => true } do |f|
```

**UPDATE**

You won't need to set the multipart attribute to true if you're on Rails 3.1, because it's handled automatically.

Comment: oh. my. gosh. You are my hero, I wish I could give you three or four upvotes. It's amazing how much a fresh set of eyes helps to find an obvious error!